# Bootstrap is capturing ArrowDown on dropdown without propagation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

My issue is that I can't navigate through `.item`s pressing `ArrowDown`. It looks that Bootstrap is capturing the key with non propagation. I can navigate if I change `ArrowDown` by `a` for example.

I'm creating a custom full accessible dropdown, because this I need bind `ArrowDown`

How can i fix it? Thanks

**Code Snippet**

```js
const dropdownMenuCombo = document.getElementById('dropdownMenuCombo');
const searchInput = document.getElementById('search');
const firstDropdownItem = document.querySelector('.item');
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".item");

// Quan es desplegui, el search pilla el focus
dropdownMenuCombo.addEventListener('shown.bs.dropdown', function() {
  console.log("dropdownMenuCombo shown");
  document.getElementById('search').focus();
});

// Accions de key a sobre del search
searchInput.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  console.log("input " + e.key);

  // Down arrow key
  if (e.key === "ArrowDown") {
    e.preventDefault();
    firstDropdownItem.tabIndex = 0;
    firstDropdownItem.focus();
  }

  // Up arrow key
  else if (e.key === "ArrowUp") {
    e.preventDefault();
    new bootstrap.Dropdown(dropdownMenuCombo, {}).toggle();
    dropdownMenuCombo.focus();
  }
});

// Accions de key a sobre d'una opció      
function handleKeyDown(event) {
  console.log("option " + event.key);

  if (event.key === "ArrowDown" || event.key === "ArrowUp") {
    event.preventDefault();

    var currentIndex = Array.from(items).indexOf(document.activeElement);

    var nextIndex =
      event.key === "ArrowDown" ?
      (currentIndex + 1) :
      (currentIndex - 1);

    if (nextIndex < 0) {
      searchInput.focus();
    }

    if (nextIndex >= items.length) {
      nextIndex = items.length - 1;
    }

    items[nextIndex].tabIndex = 0;
    items[nextIndex].focus();
  }
}

items.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
  console.log("associat keydown a  " + item.textContent);
});
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle  form-control" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="menu" data-menu-trigger="reviewers-select-menu" role="button" tabindex="9" id="dropdownMenuCombo">
    <span class="badge rounded-pill text-bg-primary">Primary</span>
    <span class="badge rounded-pill text-bg-danger">Danger</span>
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdownMenu">
    <input class="dropdown-item dropdowninputsearch" aria-label="Type or choose a user" aria-autocomplete="list" id="search" type="text" class="w-100" />
    <ul class="items">
      <li class="item" role="menuitemcheckbox" aria-checked="true" tabindex="1">Action 1</li>
      <li class="item" role="menuitemcheckbox" aria-checked="false" tabindex="1">Action 2</li>
      <li class="item" role="menuitemcheckbox" aria-checked="false" tabindex="1">Action 3</li>
      <li class="item" role="menuitemcheckbox" aria-checked="false" tabindex="1">Action 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Bootstrap 5.3 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Krampus, can you elaborate? Bootstrap documentation say: [Bootstrap’s dropdowns, on the other hand, are designed to be generic and applicable to a variety of situations and markup structures. For instance, it is possible to create dropdowns that contain additional inputs and form controls, such as search fields or login forms.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/dropdowns/#accessibility)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keydown indeed doesn't seem to work when inside Bootstrap dropdown, but only for up, down and escape keys, probably because they are controlled by Bootstrap, to allow cycling through items:

> ```
>     // if target isn't included in items (e.g. when expanding the dropdown)
>     // allow cycling to get the last item in case key equals ARROW_UP_KEY
>     getNextActiveElement(items, target, key === ARROW_DOWN_KEY, !items.includes(target)).focus()
> ```
>
> https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/js/src/dropdown.js#L336

So, Bootstrap already does this for you, you only need to use the correct CSS selectors: `class="dropdown-item"` instead of `class="item"`

example:

```
  <li class="dropdown-item" role="menuitemcheckbox" aria-checked="true" tabindex="1">Action 1</li>
```

demo:

```js
const dropdownMenuCombo = document.getElementById('dropdownMenuCombo');
const searchInput = document.getElementById('search');
const firstDropdownItem = document.querySelector('.dropdown-item');
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-item");

// Quan es desplegui, el search pilla el focus
dropdownMenuCombo.addEventListener('shown.bs.dropdown', function() {
  console.log("dropdownMenuCombo shown");
  document.getElementById('search').focus();
});

// Accions de key a sobre del search
searchInput.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  console.log("input " + e.key);

  // Down arrow key
  if (e.key === "ArrowDown") {
    e.preventDefault();
    firstDropdownItem.tabIndex = 0;
    firstDropdownItem.focus();
  }

  // Up arrow key
  else if (e.key === "ArrowUp") {
    e.preventDefault();
    new bootstrap.Dropdown(dropdownMenuCombo, {}).toggle();
    dropdownMenuCombo.focus();
  }
});

// Accions de key a sobre d'una opció      
function handleKeyDown(event) {
  console.log("option " + event.key);

  if (event.key === "ArrowDown" || event.key === "ArrowUp") {
    event.preventDefault();

    var currentIndex = Array.from(items).indexOf(document.activeElement);

    var nextIndex =
      event.key === "ArrowDown" ?
      (currentIndex + 1) :
      (currentIndex - 1);

    if (nextIndex < 0) {
      searchInput.focus();
    }

    if (nextIndex >= items.length) {
      nextIndex = items.length - 1;
    }

    items[nextIndex].tabIndex = 0;
    items[nextIndex].focus();
  }
}

items.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
  console.log("associat keydown a  " + item.textContent);
});
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle  form-control" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="menu" data-menu-trigger="reviewers-select-menu" role="button" tabindex="9" id="dropdownMenuCombo">
    <span class="badge rounded-pill text-bg-primary">Primary</span>
    <span class="badge rounded-pill text-bg-danger">Danger</span>
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdownMenu">
    <input class="dropdown-item dropdowninputsearch" aria-label="Type or choose a user" aria-autocomplete="list" id="search" type="text" class="w-100" />
    <ul class="items">
      <li class="dropdown-item" role="menuitemcheckbox" aria-checked="true" tabindex="1">Action 1</li>
      <li class="dropdown-item" role="menuitemcheckbox" aria-checked="false" tabindex="1">Action 2</li>
      <li class="dropdown-item" role="menuitemcheckbox" aria-checked="false" tabindex="1">Action 3</li>
      <li class="dropdown-item" role="menuitemcheckbox" aria-checked="false" tabindex="1">Action 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Bootstrap 5.3 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```